# Is the 'my $x if 0' trick usable for static variable creation for Perls before 5.10?

Tags: perl

In Perl before 5.10 there is no "state" declaration.

I've come across an example of creating static variables in these Perls: `my $x if 0`. The `if 0` conditional makes the variable act like a static variable:

```
use strict; use warnings;
add() for 1..7;

sub add {
    my @arr = () if 0;

    push @arr, '+';
    print @arr, "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
+
++
+++
++++
+++++
++++++
+++++++
```

Is this behaviour consistent in all versions of Perl before 5.10?

Comment: Well, not the versions before Perl 5.0 :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've always used scoping braces to create static variables.

```
add() for 1..2;       # Append to existing.
add('foo', 'bar');    # Re-initialize if args are passed.
add() for 1..2;       # Append to existing.
{
    my @arr;
    sub add {
        @arr = @_ if @_;
        push @arr, '+';
        print @arr, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

The behavior of `my $x if 0` is a bug. It has survived for a long time because it's useful and thus used; fixing it would break existing code. It's consistent and could therefore be considered usable but that doesn't mean you should do so. This "feature" has been deprecated and issues a warning as of 5.10:

```
Deprecated use of my() in false conditional
```

Even if you can't use `state` (i.e your code needs to be able to run under versions of Perl prior to 5.10) the `my $x if 0` trick is just laziness. Use a closure otherwise:

```
{
    my $x;
    sub counter {
        $x = '1' unless defined $x;
        print $x++, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: `my $x = undef if 0;` doesn't issue a warning though.

Answer (score 9):

No, it's very crummy. Use a closure instead.

```
use strict;

sub add {
    my @arr;

    return sub {
        push @arr, '+';
        print @arr, "\n";
    }
}

my $iter = add();
$iter->() for 1..7;
```

Comment: Saying "No" implies that the trick is not usable before 5.10, when in fact it is a usable bug/feature before 5.10 that the `state` keyword was introduced to fix.