# Declaring a scalar inside an if statement?

Tags: perl

Why can't I declare a scalar variable inside an if statement? Does it have something to do with the scope of the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"? Perl will allow you to do some pretty fascinating stuff. However, I suspect the developer looking at the code after you're done with it might try to kill you.

Comment: If you show us your code, we can help you fix it. If you don't, we can't.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161111/is-the-my-x-if-0-trick-usable-for-static-variable-creation-for-perls-before-5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who says you can't?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
no warnings qw(uninitialized);
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use Data::Dumper;

my $bar;

if (my $foo eq $bar) {
    say "\$foo and \$bar match";
}
else {
    say "Something freaky happened";
}

$ ./test.pl 
$foo and $bar match
```

Works perfectly! Of course it makes no sense since what are you comparing `$foo` too? It has no value.

Can you give me an example of what you're doing and the results you're getting?

Or, is this more what you mean?:

```
if (1 == 1) {
   my $foo = "bar";
   say "$foo";    #Okay, $foo is in scope
}

say "$foo;"    #Fail: $foo doesn't exist because it's out of scope
```

So, which one do you mean?

Comment: Closer to the latter one. I think the problem is/was with the scope of the var.

Comment: Yup. It's variable scope. Once you're outside the block `if` where `$foo` was declared, `$foo` no longer exists.

Comment: What you *can't* do is apparently `if(my $foo = method() and $foo eq 'bar'){}`. I keep trying this because I'm not guaranteed $foo will be defined, and an undef would cause warnings during the `eq`.

Comment: Perl takes the _C Shortcut_ when evaluating boolean statements. If the left hand side of an `and` is _false_, Perl never checks the right hand side. It allows you to say things like `if ( defined $foo and $foo eq $bar )` which works vs. `if ( $foo eq $bar and defined $foo)` which will give you a warning if `$foo` is not defined (and you, of course, are using `use warnings;`). I wouldn't know why yours wouldn't work, but I'll have to test it.

Comment: `if(my $foo = method() and $foo eq 'bar'){}` doesn't work because my doesn't work that way.  my returns the newly created lexical (so you can in fact assign to it) but the scope of that lexical where you can look it up by name only begins with the following statement.   This means this prints bar: `my $foo="bar"; { my $foo=$foo; print $foo }`

Answer (score 9):

Every block `{...}` in Perl creates a new scope.  This includes bare blocks, subroutine blocks, BEGIN blocks, control structure blocks, looping structure blocks, inline blocks (map/grep), eval blocks, and the bodies of statement modifier loops.

If a block has an initialization section, that section is considered within the scope of the following block.

```
if (my $x = some_sub()) {
    # $x in scope here
} 
# $x out of scope
```

In a statement modifier loop, the initialization section is not contained within the scope of the pseudo block:

```
$_ = 1 for my ($x, $y, $z);

# $x, $y, and $z are still in scope and each is set to 1
```

Comment: Will `$x` be in scope inside else condition in your example?

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up my comment. Statements such as the following is perfectly legal:

```
if( my( $foo, $bar ) = $baz =~ /^(.*?)=(.*?)$/ ) {
  # Do stuff
}
```

Courtesy of one of my colleagues.

Comment: The flexibility of perl is both a blessing and a curse. It allows for extremely efficient and 'fun' things being done, but at the same time it's very easy to write code that the next developer will not understand correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There's an exception: You may not conditionally declare a variable and use it under different conditions. This means the following isn't allowed:

```
my $x = ... if ...;
```

Comment: That code *will* actually parse and run fine, but it has weird, unexpected effects. Don't do it.

Comment: Well, you can, but you shouldn't since technically the behavior is undefined.  It's sane coding that prevents it, not perl itself.