# Warn if declaring a variable in a statement modifier

Tags: perl

I just came by the following line of code:

```
my $foo = $bar if $cond;
```

I'm going to fix this since it will of course lead to [subtle bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915308/1733163).

Is there a version of Perl, a module, or pragma that would warn if this type of statement was reached?

For now I'm just going to use a combination of grep and PPI to scan the codebase to fix all of these issues.  Have found a total of 102 of them thus far.  However, a way of automatically warning other programmers if they add a new invalid line would be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`Perl::Critic::Policy::Variables::ProhibitConditionalDeclarations`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Variables::ProhibitConditionalDeclarations) policy in `perlcritic` warns about these constructions.