# Perl “do { … } if …” as expression

Tags: perl, syntax, expression

`my $x = do { 3; } if 1; say $x  # works`

`my $x = (do { 3; } if 1); say $x  # syntax error`

How come? If the do block is an expression, why can't it be parenthesised? If it's not, how does the first one parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```perl
my $x = do { 3; } if 1;
```

is actually equivalent to

```perl
( my $x = do { 3; } ) if 1;
```

Note that you shouldn't execute `my` conditionally. (More precisely, you shouldn't use a `my` variable that hasn't been executed. Your code is technically ok since the `my` is always executed before `$x` is used.)

---

An expression (`my $x = do { ... }`) modified by a statement modifier (`if 1`) is a statement.

The inside of parens must be an *expression*, not a *statement*.

You can't do

- `( $x = 3; )`
- `( sub f { } )`
- `( if (f()) { g() } )`
- `( g() if f(); )`
- `( g() if f() )`

You get the idea.

Comment: Ah, finally. Yes, with if 0 I get a compile error. Thought I've tried that...

Answer (score 8):

A [compound statement](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements) used for flow control (`if BLOCK`), as well as one with the *statement modifier* (used here, the postfix `if`), cannot appear inside parenthesis.

This restriction makes sense since such a statement [may or *may not*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers) return a value

> `if` executes the statement once *if* and only if the condition is true.

(original emphasis)

---

A side note. The first example runs without warnings but it has *undefined behavior*, what must be avoided. From the end of the section [Statement Modifiers in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers)

> **NOTE:** The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...`) is **undefined**. The value of the `my` variable may be `undef`, any previously assigned value, or possibly anything else. Don't rely on it. Future versions of perl might do something different from the version of perl you try it out on. Here be dragons.

(original emphasis)

Any instances of this should be rewritten, and `Perl::Critic` has a [policy for it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057424/4653379), making it easier to find them

Comment: Ok,  but then how does the first example parse? How can `do { … } if … ` be an r-value?

Comment: @AldIn It's not do–if but more like `(my $x = ...) if ...`: the `if` modifies the entire statement, and `do { ... }` is an expression.

Comment: I've thought of that, but in that case shouldn't $x be scoped to just the declaration (in which case “say $x” wouldn't work?)

Comment: @AldIn The first example exhibits _undefined behavior_, because it mixes compile-time and run-time effects (so to say); that's documented and there have been questions on this here.  If you were to say `$x = do { ... } if $c;` then that'd be fine (no compile-time `my`). The `do` statement returns so that would be like `$x = 3 if $c;`  (This is unrelated to the problem in the second example, of course.)

Comment: @AldIn The documentation I mentioned is at the end of the section [Statement Modifiers in perlsyn page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers) (second link in my answer)

Comment: (In my comment above it says "_The `do` statement returns..._"  --- it's not a "statement," of course, but an expression. The point being that `do {...}` returns a value which then gets assigned and so _that_ (assignment) can be conditioned, etc)

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the `do` that's the problem, it's the postfix `if`. That postfix can't appear inside the parens:

```
$ perl -E 'my $x = ( 1 if 1); say $x'
syntax error at -e line 1, near "1 if"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Instead, you can use the conditional operator `?:` with a `do` in one of the branches:

```
$ perl -E 'my $x = ( time % 2 ? do { 1 } : () ); say $x'
```

Comment: Then I wonder what “my $x = 1 if $ARGV[0]; say $x” means... Declare $x only if argument is truthy? Obviously not.

Comment: `my ... if ...` can make the runtime effect of the declaration omitted, which is problematic.  "The behaviour of a my, state, or our modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, my $x if ...) is undefined" - https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn

Comment: Don't declare variables with a postfix conidtional: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2019/07/no-more-false-postfix-lexical-declarations-in-v5-30/

Answer (score 0):

`if 1` is a *statement* modifier. `my $x = do { 3; }` is a statement; `do { 3; }` is an *expression*.