# Local variable retaining value

Tags: perl, variables, scope

So, I just tracked down a bug which can be demonstrated in this trivial subroutine:

```
sub foo {
    my $bar = shift or die "Missing bar", # <--- not a semicolon
    my @items = ();
    push @items, $bar;
    return @items;
}
```

Obviously the mistake is that the first line of the subroutine ends in a comma. This had some rather unusual consequences, as can be seen:

```
say foo(1); # 1
say foo(1); # 11
say foo(1); # 111
say foo(1); # 1111
```

Now, I understand that this isn't a syntax error because of how the comma operator works. I understand that `@items` is not being set to `()` because the right side of the `or` isn't being reached. My question is, how can a variable declared with `my` inside of a subroutine allow data to persist between subroutine calls? It seems as if the `my` is turning into an `our` somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`B::Deparse`](http://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse)  is invaluable in exercises like this:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse 31191808.pl
sub foo {
    die 'Missing bar', my(@items) = () unless my $bar = shift @_;
    push @items, $bar;
    return @items;
}
```

which makes this a variant of the [`my $var if 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161111/is-the-my-x-if-0-trick-usable-for-static-variable-creation-for-perls-before-5) trick/bug/curiosity. Its effect is to create a lexical but static variable, which will not be reinitialized each time `foo` is called.

Answer (score 3):

You have discovered the [`comma-operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator)

From perldoc perlop:

> Binary "," is the comma operator. In scalar context it evaluates its
>   left argument, throws that value away, then evaluates its right
>   argument and returns that value.

So this is actually considered a single statement:

```
my $bar = shift or die "Missing bar", my @items = ();
```

Perl evaluates the LHS and discards the result, since this is an assignment that doesn't really discard anything `1` is still assigned to `$bar`, then evaluates the RHS and returns that value. An important note here is that this means that `@items` is initialized as a static lexical variable within your sub, but remains static across calls to `foo()`. Similar to how [`state`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) variables work.

At this point in the subroutine you have assigned `1` to `$bar`. The next line is:

```
push @items, $bar;
```

Perl pushes `$bar` onto the static lexical variable `@items`. The next statement returns a list of a single element `1`.

Subsequent calls to `foo` continue to add elements to `@items` array and then return these elements. This is why you see an increasing number of `1` from your subroutine calls.

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer. It is NOT a global variable. I'm using strict and warnings, and the variable is not accessible outside of the subroutine.

Comment: @AKHolland sorry, I had revised the second paragraph after I realized it wasn't global but forgot to modify the later ones.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is very similar to this snippet :

```
use v5.14; # Implies strict
sub foo {
    my @something= () if 0;
    push @something, shift;
    say @something;
}

foo($_) for 1..5;
```

The output will be :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

In Perl, **conditionally declaring a variable makes it only assign a value whenever that condition is true**. If you changed the `if 0` to `if $_[0] == 3`, you'd get a completely different sequence of numbers. This is actually an old bug in Perl that cannot be fixed anymore because a lot of code might depend on it, but if you're lucky you might see this warning: *"Deprecated use of my() in false conditional"*